# Yii2. Authorised users list

Tags: session, authorization, yii2

I've used standard yii2 functions for authorization. User sessions are stored in database.
How can I get the list of all authorized users in Yii2?

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    $sessions = (new Query())->select('*')->from('session')->where('expire > :now', [
        ':now' => time()
    ])->all();

    foreach($sessions as $session) {
        $sessionData = Yii::$app->session->readSession($session['id']);
        $sessionUnserializedData = $this->unserialize_session($sessionData);
        $userId = $sessionUnserializedData['__id'];
        echo $userId;
    }
```

unserialize_session method get from @phred [gist](https://gist.github.com/phred/1201412).